# Parsing of loadHTMLString when using stringWithFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Have a series of YouTube videos that I want to embed without having to rewrite the embed code each time, so have used stringWithFormat to dynamically insert the URL:

```
videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
<html>\
<head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
iframe {position:absolute; top:100%; margin-top:-150px;}\
body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
</style>\
</head>\
<body>\
<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
</body>\
</html>", videoURL];

[videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

When I log the result, it looks HTML fine, but it isn't rendered correctly in the simulator, the scale and position of the thumbnail is wrong. If I simply hardcode the URL into the string then it works fine. So I'm guessing it's a problem with stringWithFormat?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When using `-stringWithFormat:`, you need to escape the `%` character literals in the string with another `%` character**

```
NSString *htmlFormatString = [@"
<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
iframe {position:absolute; top:100%; margin-top:-150px;}
body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>" stringByAppendingFormat:@"<iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>", videoURL];

[videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, would never have figured that out myself, will give it a go.